# Magento 2 | Change sort order for search results

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch, sorting, product-sorting

I would like to set as the default order in the search results page "relevance" in descending order.

How can i do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named **catalogsearch_result_index.xml** at Venodr\Module\view\frontend\layout and paste the following code

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
 <referenceContainer name="content">
        <referenceBlock class="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct" name="search_result_list">
            <action method="setDefaultDirection">
                <argument name="dir" xsi:type="string">
                asc
                </argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Now **setDefaultDirection** accordingly